# combine 2 similar row in column 1 and merge second column text in r

Tags: r, merge, row

How can I combine the row who has the same value on column1 and format the merge of column2 properly (see example) ?

Input:

```
  > df
      COL1    COL2
    1  b21 blabla1
    2  b21 blabla2
    3  b55  sdlafk
```

Desired output (2 row because b21 is combined in 1 row):

```
      COL1    COL2
    1  b21 blabla1
           blabla2
    2  b55  sdlafk
```

Source

```
df <- structure(list(COL1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("b21", 
"b55"), class = "factor"), COL2 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("blabla1", 
"blabla2", "sdlafk"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("COL1", 
"COL2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Do you still want a data.frame? Should values in `Col2` be pasted together or just be in a list if `col1` is the same?

Comment: Any solution is welcome

Answer (score 0):

If you want `Col2` to be stored in a list:

```
data.table::setDT(df)[, .(COL2 = list(COL2)), .(COL1)]
   COL1            COL2
1:  b21 blabla1,blabla2
2:  b55          sdlafk
```

If you want to convert it to a character:

```
data.table::setDT(df)[, .(COL2 = paste(COL2, collapse = ",")), .(COL1)]
   COL1            COL2
1:  b21 blabla1,blabla2
2:  b55          sdlafk
```

You can use base `R` also:

```
aggregate(COL2 ~ COL1, df, paste, collapse = ",")
  COL1            COL2
1  b21 blabla1,blabla2
2  b55          sdlafk
```

Answer (score 0):

Several options, depending on what your goal is (presentation versus storage):

```
 df <- data.frame(COL1 = c("b21", "b21", "b55"),
                  COL2 = c("blabla1", "blabla2", "sdlafk"))
```

Simple list:

```
split(df$COL2, df$COL1)
# $b21
# [1] "blabla1" "blabla2"
# $b55
# [1] "sdlafk"
```

Presentation-only:

```
within(df, { COL1 = ifelse(duplicated(COL1), "", COL1) })
#   COL1    COL2
# 1  b21 blabla1
# 2      blabla2
# 3  b55  sdlafk
```

`dplyr` (to complement @Psidom's `data.table`):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(COL1) %>%
  summarize(COL2 = paste(COL2, collapse = ","))
# Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
#    COL1            COL2
#   <chr>           <chr>
# 1   b21 blabla1,blabla2
# 2   b55          sdlafk
```